# How do I Insert an image into email body?

Tags: email, go, email-attachments

I want to send a image in email body using go lang.
Used this package from `github`

https://github.com/scorredoira/email

```
    err := m.Attach("image.png")
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err1)
    }
```

Now i am able to send image file as attachment but my need is to send a image file in email body.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/scorredoira/email/blob/master/email.go#L55

Comment: how to use those function? @kostix

Comment: Why not just try it? The function signature is the same a Attach. Though, it's been a while since I read the specs, but the code doesn't look right to me, as it only sets a Content-Type of "message/rfc822", and no Content-Transfer-Encoding. (maybe email clients just figure it out on their own even if it's not correct per the RFCs)

Comment: @JimB, it won't also properly encode filename of the attached file, should it contain characters outside of the US-ASCII repertoire. A seemilgly more popular alternative, `gomail`, won't do that either but at least it has hooks allowing the programmer to arrange for providing the correct headers theirselves. I guessed dumping this on the OP would be a bit over the top though: I suppose it's better to solve one problem at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail) (I'm the author). Have a look at the [Embed method](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Message.Embed) which allow you to embed images in the email body:

```
package main

import "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "from@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "to@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
    m.Embed("image.png")
    m.SetBody("text/html", `<img src="cid:image.png" alt="My image" />`)

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")

    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set `default dimension` for that image.?? @Ale

Comment: As you would in an HTML page: use the `width` HTML attribute or the `width` CSS property.

Comment: Awesome :-)...This package is very useful for me.

Comment: @Ale Im attempting to do something similar using your `Gomail`, mind checking out my question?...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113598/how-to-add-image-to-html-body-of-an-email-go