# How to add image to html body of an email (Go)

Tags: javascript, email, canvas, go, email-attachments

I am using [Gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail)

I am attempting to send an email to myself. I have figured out how to do so, but now I want to add an image, either in the html body or as an attachment (does not really matter). I just need to be able to see the image in my email.

First off, I am sending the `img` `src` through a `POST` request, which I then save into the following `struct`...

```
type test_struct struct {
    Test string `json:"image"`
}
```

I then try to attach it in the email body like so...

```
mail := gomail.NewMessage()
mail.SetHeader("From", "XXXX@gmail.com")
mail.SetHeader("To", "XXXX@gmail.com")
mail.SetHeader("Subject", "IMAGE!")

mail.SetBody("text/html", `<img src="cid:t.Test" alt="My Image"/>`)
```

this did not work, so I tried to use [Embed method](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Message.Embed)...

```
mail.Embed(t.Test)
```

This gave me a blank image with the error the filename or extension is too long. Not sure if this is important, but note that the `src` I got is from `HTML5` Canvas. I got the source of the image from Canvas...

```
localCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

And this is the value I save in `t.Test`...

```
buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
reader := bytes.NewReader(buf)

var t test_struct

err = json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&t)
```

The string being save in the `t.Test` is of the following format...

```
data:image/png:base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAgA...
```

How can I send this to my email? The documentation only gets me so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Insert an image into email body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790771/how-do-i-insert-an-image-into-email-body)

Comment: Is `t.Test` the image or the filename ?

Comment: @JohnSPerayil it is the image itself I believe

Comment: @Bolboa what do you get when you print `t.Test`?

Comment: @Motakjuq Its a very long string of numbers and letter. Way to long to paste here. Also I edited my answer to show how I save it.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil I don't believe it is a duplicate as I have already tried those answers to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, check if the data in t.Test is correct (if contains the filename, path, or whatever you need to reference the image)

Well, you have some options, first, if it's ok just attaching the image, you only should do:

```
mail.Attach("/path/of/your/image/image.png")
```

But, if you need to use the image in the message, you have some alternatives.

Alt 1: Use `Embed` method

You must to have the image in your filesystem, because the method is defined in that way. You have to do something like:

```
mail.SetBody("text/html", "Image <img src=\"cid:tux.png\"/>")
mail.Embed("/path/of/your/image/tux.png")
```

You must to use the image name, in this case `tux.png`, when you add it in the html body with the `img` tag, you have to define the `src` like `cid:tux.png`

Alt 2: Use a base64 encoding

For this you need to know the mime type of the image file, in my example is a png file, so the mime is `image/png`. Also, you have to encode the image as base64.

```
img, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/of/your/image/tux.png")
if err != nil {
    // check errors
}
out := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(img)
```

Or, if you don't have the image in the filesystem, but you have it in a variable (`[]byte` type), you can use it with `EncodeToString`

```
var imageData []byte
// in some part, you load the image data into imageData
out := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(imageData)
```

And you use it like

```
mail.SetBody("text/html", fmt.Sprintf("Image <img src=\"data:image/png;base64,%s\"/>", out))
```

So, when you use `img`, you have to set in `src` an embedded image with `data:mime_type;base64,image_encoded_base64`, if we look the example, is `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...`

**EDIT:**

I created an example with the JSON request and the handler [Example](https://gist.github.com/Motakjuq/9b403498b042a037e0d1e43c06a53263)

Comment: I tried convert `t.Test` to `[]byte(t.Test)` and then using your method...but its prints out the entire byte array as the image source

Comment: I think the `html` is not getting rendered. I am seeing the `tags` not the image itself

Comment: @Bolboa your img format is `data:image/png:base64, iVBORw0.....`, you only need to replate the `:` after `image/png` with a `;` and use it with `fmt.Sprintf("<img src=\"%s\"/>", yourImageEncoded)`

Comment: it still isn't rendering the image. I must be doing something wrong. I'm sending the string in json format to the go server. On receipt I decode it as shown above. Then I place it in my `src` as you said. But it does not read the `src` because the image is blank. ( I replaced the `:` too)

Comment: @bolboa check the example